# Is there an easy way to install RMagick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, image

I am trying to install RMagick on my slicehost(Linux Hardy)
instead of compile from source, here is what I did:

```
$ sudo aptitude install -y imagemagick
$ sudo aptitude install -y libmagick9-dev
$ sudo gem install rmagick
```

After installed, it reads GIF with no problem, however for JPEG and PNG, I keep getting this error:

```
Magick::ImageMagickError: no decode delegate for this image format
```

I know it is probably because I don't have libpng and libjpg libraries, but i didn't find guide on how to install these. I compiled libpng and libjpg from source, with no luck, the files are in the /usr/lib, but i still getting the error.

Answer (score 2):

I found this to be very help: [how to install rmagick on linux](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-linux.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Installing ImageMagick from Source](http://www.digitalsanctum.com/2009/03/18/installing-imagemagick-from-source-on-ubuntu-804/)

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to follow the recommendation here:
http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-faq.html#delegate

It's probably more likely that everything is fine, but you need to reconfigure your image magick install after adding the jpeg delegate.