# Ruby: Installing rmagick on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm trying to get RMagick setup on Ubuntu 10.04. Looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482823/is-there-an-easy-way-to-install-rmagick) but had no joy. I even compiled and installed ImageMagick from source, but the instructions [here](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-linux.html) still didn't help me when I try to install RMagick using RubyGems. I got this error:

```
carcher@carcher-laptop:~/Code/temp/RMagick-2.13.1$ sudo gem install rmagick
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
extconf.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)
 from extconf.rb:1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
carcher@carcher-laptop:~/Code/temp/RMagick-2.13.1$
```

What does it all mean? :)  I'm new to Ruby and RubyGems so please be gentle. My setup is as follows:

```
Ruby: 1.8.7
RubyGems: 1.3.7
```

I'm pretty much out of ideas (and tired too!). I tired to compile RMagick from source using the link above but it failed as there was no `./configure` script :(

Any and all help appreciated!

Comment: Most of these answers are different than the official docs, You should install `imagemagick`, `libmagickcore-dev`, and `libmagickwand-dev`: https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/wiki/Installing-on-Ubuntu

Answer (score 274, accepted):

Install the packages `imagemagick` and `libmagickwand-dev` (or `libmagick9-dev`). You should then be able to install the Rmagick Gem.

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev
```

If not, you are missing ruby related development packages like `build-essential` and `ruby1.8-dev`. If that's the case, a generic "ubuntu install ruby 1.8" query in google should sort you out.

Comment: This (imagemagick and libmagickwand-dev) appears to have worked and I can see RMagick 2.13.1 as one of my listed gems!

Comment: As I commented below, worked fine for me just now with just libmagickwand-dev and I didn't need any additional packages.  At least for Magick::ImageList.from_blob, Magick::ImageList.resize, and Magick::ImageList.write.  Not sure about other methods.

Comment: This is by the far the quickest answer! AMAZING!

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS you have to first install libmagickcore-dev and then libmagickwand-dev, otherwise apt-get will refuse to install the wand dev package. (You should be able to install them in one command line, as follows: `sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev`) (source: http://askubuntu.com/questions/112548/rmagick-install-problem/112551#112551)

Comment: In my case - after a lot of trying, apt-get told me that libmagickwand-dev requires libmagickcore-dev but is not going to be installed. I run `sudo apt-get install libmagickcore-dev` before magigwand and it helped :)

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, when i run the command sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev. Its giving error The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagickwand-dev : Depends: libmagickwand-6.q16-dev but it is not going to be installed

Answer (score 63):

You don't need a lot of the other junk in these answers, just:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

Comment: I can confirm this worked on Ubuntu 14.04. As a side note, you also need the packages `ruby-dev` and `make`...which may already be there on a typical system, but weren't there on the docker image.

Comment: You also need the `imagemagick` package: https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/wiki/Installing-on-Ubuntu

Comment: After searching for about an hour, Dan Allen's comment ^ (about installing `make` and `ruby-dev`) finally fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Do not forget to do: `sudo apt-get update` before this.

Answer (score 29):

On **Ubuntu 12.04** `libmagick9-dev` is gone. `graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat` should be used instead.

```
apt-get install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat
```

Comment: To clarify for 12.04: sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat

Comment: You should install `imagemagick` as well: https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/wiki/Installing-on-Ubuntu

Answer (score 25):

On **Ubuntu 15.04**, what solved it for me was to remove all previous *magick installations, reinstall required packages and then symlink the config file:

```
sudo apt-get purge graphicsmagick graphicsmagick-dbg imagemagick-common imagemagick imagemagick-6.q16 libmagickcore-6-headers libmagickwand-dev graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16/Magick-config /usr/bin/Magick-config
gem install rmagick
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I think all the other Ubuntu answers are outdated.

Comment: Thanks.  That worked for me after upgrading 14.04 to 16.04.

Comment: This solution not working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, when run the command sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev, giving error "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagickwand-dev : Depends: libmagickwand-6.q16-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages"

Answer (score 16):

In Ubuntu 14.04

---

Below code is worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
```

Then,

```
gem install rmagick
```

Answer (score 12):

On **Ubuntu 12.0.4.2** `sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev libmagickcore-dev libmagickcore4-extra libgraphviz-dev libgvc5` worked for me.

graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat installed but didn't include the header files so rmagick wouldn't compile.

Please note, you need to remove graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat before running the command above.

Comment: Thanks for this - it was the only solution here that worked for me.

Comment: You should install `imagemagick` as well: https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/wiki/Installing-on-Ubuntu

Answer (score 7):

this worked for me...

```
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat libmagickwand-dev 

gem install rmagick

...

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed rmagick-2.13.1
1 gem installed
```

(ubuntu 12.0.4 64bit)

Comment: You should install `imagemagick` as well: https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/wiki/Installing-on-Ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

You got message `extconf.rb:1:in 'require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)` because package `ruby1.8-dev` isn't installed. Install it (`sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev`) and try again.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 13.10

This code worked for me

sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat libmagickwand-dev

gem install rmagick

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu, you can run:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

On Centos, you can run:

```
sudo yum install gcc ImageMagick-devel make which
```

Then install

```
gem install rmagick
```

Answer (score 2):

To get bundle to stop failing on ubuntu 12.04.

```
apt-get install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat libmagickwand-dev
```

This is my gemfile

```
gem 'rmagick' 
gem 'mini_magick'
```

Comment: You should install `imagemagick` as well: https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/wiki/Installing-on-Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try installing the native deb package instead of the gem, be aware that the librmagick-ruby was broken on Ubuntu 10.04 until just very recently:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/librmagick-ruby/+bug/518122

See comment #17 in particular.  I believe this has already been fixed so now `apt-get install librmagick-ruby` might "just work".  Otherwise here's how to build it yourself from source

```
$ cd /usr/src
$ sudo apt-get build-dep librmagick-ruby
$ sudo apt-get source librmagick-ruby
$ cd librmagick-ruby-2.11.1
$ sudo dch -i
(add changelog entry)
$ sudo dpkg-buildpackage
$ cd ..
$ sudo dpkg -i librmagick-ruby*.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 16.04.3:

This i worked:

`sudo apt install imagemagick imagemagick-6.q16`

It means this installed imagemagick then you can run RMagick.

Comment: This solution is not working form in ubuntu 16.04.3, showing error "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagickwand-dev : Depends: libmagickwand-6.q16-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux then simply run these commands.

```
 sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev
```

and then

```
 bundle install
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.

And if you are using mac then simply run following commands

First of all unlink your installed imagemagick which was not properly installed in latest mac high sierra by using.

```
 brew unlink imagemagick
```

then install latest imagemagic6 using below command

```
 brew install imagemagick@6 && brew link imagemagick@6 --force
```

Then install gem rmagick using below command

```
 gem install rmagick 

 bundle install
```

It will work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow below 3 steps proven on UBUNTU 16.04**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential imagemagick libmagickwand-dev

#In .bashrc or .bash_profile add below code. Just check the ImageMagick dir name.
export PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16:$PATH"
gem install rmagic #Install Gem
```