# Bundle install gives me error for rmagick on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu, rmagick, ubuntu-15.04

I am trying to do `bundle install`

but when trying it gives me error as

`Can't install RMagick 0.0.0. Can't find Magick-config`

Tried goggling for solution but none of the solution worked for me.

I also tried installing gem rmagick before doing bundle install but it also give me error where as I checked the installed location is has the file named `MagickWand.h`

```
Can't install RMagick 2.15.4. Can't find MagickWand.h.
```

Please help me on this

Answer (score 2):

you need the `imagemagick` library on your ubuntu machine.

This package includes all the static libraries needed to compile programs using `MagickWand`. It contains the MagickWand.h file

Just Run this from your terminal.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

it will install all the missing libraires.
then run `bundle install` again, it will work .

Comment: thanks for such a quick reply, this I already tried. But it didn't worked. 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704919/installing-rmagick-on-ubuntu?rq=1' In this answer by mike helped me

Comment: it worked for me on ubuntu 15.10, Try this on ubuntu 15.04 sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev

Answer (score 0):

You need to install imagemagic

```
sudo -i

cd

apt-get install build-essential checkinstall && apt-get build-dep imagemagick -y

wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick-6.8.9-1.tar.gz
tar xzvf ImageMagick-6.8.9-1.tar.gz

cd ImageMagick-6.8.9-1/

./configure --prefix=/opt/imagemagick-6.8 && make

checkinstall
```

for more details see [This](https://gist.github.com/rodleviton/74e22e952bd6e7e5bee1)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I tried every solution on stackoverflow from making symlinks to installing libraries.

In the end, only install the required version of ImageMagick worked for me.

You can find instructions for it from [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php) and source files from [here](https://imagemagick.org/download/)

**Edit:**

1. Download the source code of required version of ImageMagick from [here](https://imagemagick.org/download/)
2. `cd /path/to/downloaded/file`
3. `tar xvzf ImageMagick.tar.gz`
4. `cd ImageMagick-x.x.x`
5. `./configure`
6. `make`
7. `sudo make install`

You may need to configure the dynamic linker run-time bindings by 
`sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib`

or adding this to `.bashrc` file
 `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib"`

Comment: It might just help to elaborate the details from the instructions provided in the links, here (directly) as those details might change / be updated over time.