# how can i install rmagick on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ubuntu-17.04

[Installing rmagick on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704919/installing-rmagick-on-ubuntu)
there are solutions for different versions of ubuntu, but none worked on 17.04 ?

`sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev` gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagickwand-dev : Depends: imagemagick-6-common (= 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-3ubuntu1) but 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-3ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
                     Depends: libmagickwand-6.q16-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Couldn't find any solution for this. Updated to Ubuntu to 17.10, where it works fine.

Comment: You might consider https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick, which is practically a drop-in replacement with easier installation and improved resource usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for any packages in ubuntu doing a `sudo apt-cache search libmagickwand-dev` and if you find the package you are looking for then install it doing `sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev`,

Installing all the unmet dependencies should fix the problem, and it is always helpful to do the commands below to upgrade any missing packages

```
sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get update
```

You should be able to install `rmagick` without any issues after this.